# how do I remove numbers from this comma seperated texts?

Tags: php, string

```
web,search,web2.0,1,seo,networking,social
web,search,web2.0,3,seo,networking,social
web,search,web2.0,4,seo,networking,social
```

How do I remove `1`, `3` and `4` from above lines??

Comment: and the zero to be removed as well?

Comment: By what logic? Because it's a number > 0? Because it's in the fifth column? Because it comes after a `0,`? Please define a clear rule

Comment: nop I want get rid of that number to perform another anlytics..@ajreal that is not 0 it si web2.0 it must remain

Comment: ic, so the `0` is not a number ... icic...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var_dump(
  implode(
    ',',
    array_filter(
      explode(',',$e),
      create_function('$a','return !is_numeric($a);')
    )
  )
);
```

results in:

```
string(39) "web,search,web2.0,seo,networking,social"
string(39) "web,search,web2.0,seo,networking,social"
string(39) "web,search,web2.0,seo,networking,social"
```

The breakdown:

- [`expode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)
  Break the array in to tokens, separated by commas.
- [`array_filter()`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)
  Take out the elements you don't want (the numbers)
- [`create_function()`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.create-function.php)
  Lazy-man's way of making a function to do the filtering (each element is passed to be decided if it stays or goes)
- [`implode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)
  Opposite of explode

Answer (score 2):

With regular expression you can replace ",[0-9]*,?" by "," maybe

Answer (score 1):

PHP has a built in csv parser: http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php

I'd recommend using the parser and then writing your data back out using fputcsv().

Answer (score 0):

Is it always the same format?

```
$string = ...;
$tab = explode(',', $string);
unset($tab[3]);
$string = implode(',', $tab);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming each line is a string

```
$mystring="web,search,web2.0,1,seo,networking,social";
$temp = explode(",", $mystring);
$mystring="";
for($i=0;$i<count($temp);$i++) {
    if(is_int($temp[$i])==false)
$mystring+=$temp[$i];
if($i <count($temp)-1)
$mystring+=",";
}
```